# Using Google Analytics in an enqueued JS file

Tags: php, javascript, html, wp-enqueue-script

I have a JS file `custom-head.js` that I have enqueued to run in the header as noted in `functions.php` here:

```
function enqueue_files() { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'head_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-head.js', array('jquery'), null, false);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_files' );
```

Within that file I want to include my Google Analytics code.  Yes, I realize I can add it to header.php or functions.php, but ideally I want to keep all of my scripts that are designed to be in the header in this one `custom-head.js` file.

```
//Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxxxx"

//check if on the live domain versus dev
if (document.location.hostname == 'website.com') {
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-xxxxx');
}

});
```

However, I am not getting the tag to fire correctly. Can you please advise on how to add these scripts?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Is the custom-head.js not loaded? Does it not execute the code? Your code is different [than the official example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/#install_the_global_site_tag), are you 100% sure non of the extra code does something unexpected?

Comment: I don't think this will work as well as you hoped, the Google analytics tag is designed to be put in the header. Placing it in a separate script may cause problems related to security policies and caching, as well as reduced accuracy. Which is probably why you're having this issue

Comment: @kero - Adding the IF statement to check the domain is 100% ok.  This code works with the <script> tags in header.php or functions.php with a hook to the head.  @Tom the js file is loading in the`<head>` correctly and adding custom analytics dimensions in other scripts works as expected.  Any other thoughts on the code itself?

Comment: Eliminate possibilities.  Temporarily paste your final GA code in header.php and test.  If it works, there is a problem with how you are getting it to the page.  If it does not, the code itself has an issue.  We load ours via a GTM container and two include files instead of enqueueing them.  As long as the script is in the page source when the browser renders the page, you should be OK.

Comment: @jdm2112 - yes, it works if I do it in header.php or functions.php.  I use GTM when I have custom dimensions, but not for out of the box analytics.  So as you look at the code, that looks correct?